# jQuery/JavaScript Pop Up window with Django (select from child, display on parent)

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, popup, window.open

What I want help on is, when a user clicks a link (existing images), it opens a window (I have done this).  In this window I have a list of current images on the server,  If a user selects a image (via radio button - then submits),  it passes the id from the child to the parent.

I tried manipulating a js calendar pop-up script,  but with no luck.   I am not a good js/jQuery coder, and I hope that someone can help me with this, nice and simple.

I am using Django as my backend code if that makes any difference.

Thanks

Comment: phpmyadmin uses this for custom queries - maybe you could find something helpful in their source?

Comment: You want new window popup or lightbox like popup?

Comment: a popup is what I want - nothing too fancy, it's only being used internal at work.

Comment: I think I eventually found a perfect tutorial that does almost exactly what I wanted, here is the URL - http://www.webreference.com/js/tutorial1/opener.html